# Filtering aws logs via python cdk - filter log pattern errors

Tags: aws-cli

I am able to run a query in CloudWatch logs with no issues...

`filter eventName = 'SomeEvent' and responseElements.someId in ['string1', 'string2']`

I am now trying to replicate the same in python because I have to do this for many ids.

via...

```
result = cw.filter_log_events(
    logGroupName='/some-log-group',
    startTime=start_time,
    endTime=end_time,
    filterPattern=filter_pattern,
    limit=1000
)
```

where the filter patterns are defined below.

This works...

```
filter_pattern = { $.name = "SomeName" }
```

This does not...

```
ids = ['string1','string2','string3']
ids_pattern = '|'.join(ids)
filter_pattern = f'{{ $.name = "SomeName" && $.responseElements.someId like /{ids_pattern}/ }}'
```

Nor does this...

```
ids = ['string1','string2','string3']
ids_pattern = ','.join(ids)
filter_pattern = f'{{ $.name = "SomeName" && $.responseElements.someId in [{ids_pattern}] }}'
```

Error - `when calling the FilterLogEvents operation: Invalid filter pattern`

Documentation here...
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html

Does not make it clear if either `like` or `in` is supported but wondering if this is the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bad documentation since it looks like `in` or `like` may not be supported while the errors do nothing to help figure that out.

Instead went with...

```
{ $.name = "SomeName" && ($.responseElements.someId = "string1" || $.responseElements.someId = "string2") }
```